# C# MergeArea Error Microsoft.office.interop.excel

Tags: c#

I want to get the mergeArea cells from my excel sheet. for the code i use the Microsoft.office.interop.excel.dll

Running the program I get an error (0x800a03ec (-2146827284))

```
if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application variable = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")));
            Workbook variable1 = variable.Workbooks.Open(filename, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            Worksheet item = (Worksheet)((dynamic)variable1.Worksheets[1]);
            Range usedRange = item.UsedRange;
            int count = usedRange.Columns.Count;
            int num = usedRange.Rows.Count; 
            Range mergeArea = cells.MergeArea;
```

Comment: What is the error _exactly_? This is not a meaningful one.

Comment: What is `cells`? Its definition and assigning is not shown in your code

Answer (score 0):

That error code specifically means that Excel can't find something you've asked if for; from the code snippet, I suspect it might be this line:

```
Worksheet item = (Worksheet)((dynamic)variable1.Worksheets[1]);
```

Are you sure there are multiple sheets in the file? Which line does it actually throw the exception on?